# Canopy working with Enthought

Tags: enthought, canopy

I've been using the Enthought Python Distribution for about a month, and like it a lot. I test my code in ipython, which gives me the following when I launch it in a terminal :

```
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com

Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 11:14:05) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

I'm now looking for an IDE, and I've come across problems with Canopy - specifically, getting it to use my Enthought distribution as their live consoles, much like my ipython works.

I can't find anywhere to change the interpreter under Canopy. When it launches, it gives me

```
Welcome to Canopy's interactive data-analysis environment!
 with pylab-backend set to: None
Type '?' for more information.
```

This isn't using EPD, and thus, isn't using any of the packages that I've got installed.

Any ideas would be fantastic !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23614903-Canopy-is-a-new-install-not-an-in-place-update-of-EPD) should answer your question.

In brief, there is no way at present to change the interpreter in Canopy. However, Canopy is built on an improved version of EPD.

So you would need to re-install your packages into Canopy. However you should never need to do this again, even when Python is updated (e.g. eventually to 2.7.5) -- whereas with EPD, whenever the interpreter changed, you had to reinstall and start from scratch.

If you do install Canopy 1.0.0, be sure to update to 1.0.1 (from Help menu) before installing your other packages.